# Urdu font problem in ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I am new to `Ubuntu` and experiencing problem of urdu font. On some websites(such as bbcurdu) it appears correct and some places it do not (specifically facebook). I have tried to install font-nafees but no luck!

I have also tried `firefox` and `chrome` but problem persists.

Comment: Could you add website URLs? Also, add more detailed description about what is correct and what is not. Is knowledge of Urdu necessary or visibly different to anyone?

Comment: [This link](http://dunya.com.pk) is not visible correctly where some of the words are not shown correctly. and [this link](http://www.bbc.com/urdu) is correctly visible.

Comment: I still have no idea what "correctly" is. Do you mean visibly incorrect or just text characters are valid but incorrect in context. If visibly incorrect, could you add a screenshot of the incorrectly displayed page?

Comment: Also I noticed that *dunya.com.pk* has a "Download Font" button at the top of the page, though it seems to be Windows fonts. Maybe they are using a unique font? Are there other web sites that are incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for your continuous input.
Characters are valid but incorrect in context. It has option to download but that is .exe file. `Facebook` also faces same problem. I think it is a type of font, when displayed on a website it causes problems.

Comment: I would send feedback to the problem web sites if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
```

I have find this helpful for Nepali Fonts. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Correctly installed but does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing these Core Fonts available in Windows. Open **Terminal** and type this:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: Correctly installed but does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this addon with firefox can adjust font and height
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/urdu-font-size-change/?src=search